# Dynamically Read all possible formats of dates in R

Tags: r, date

I am trying to dynamically read dates in R from csv or xlsx files. Challenge is the dates could be in all possible formats of dates like combination of %d for Day, %m or %b or %B for month and %y or %Y for year and in any sequence of day, month and Year.

Are there any ready made functions that I can use or is reading characters from a series of dates and then determining which format it could be, as a solution.

Any pointers, highly appreciated.

Comment: You can check `anytime::anydate` or `anytime::anytime`  It already have many formats.  If the format is not available, then use `addFormats` after checking `getFormats`

Comment: Check out http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-import.html, section 11.3.4 for how `readr` guesses dates.

Comment: Obligatory warning to be careful with an assumed date format with the difference between dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `findAndTransformDates` from `dataPreparation` will find auomaticaly the format in each columns and transform them.

NB: it only works if you have the same format in all rows of one columns.

For example:

```
require(dataPreparation)
data("messy_adult")
head(messy_adult[, .(date1, date2, date3, date4)])
        date1      date2       date3           date4
1: 2017-10-07         NA 19-Jan-2017 21-January-2017
2: 2017-31-12 1513465200 06-Jun-2017    08-June-2017
3: 2017-12-10 1511305200 03-Jul-2017    05-July-2017
4: 2017-06-09 1485126000 19-Jul-2017    21-July-2017
5: 2017-02-03 1498345200 16-May-2017     18-May-2017
6: 2017-04-10 1503183600 02-Apr-2017   04-April-2017

messy_adult <- findAndTransformDates(messy_adult)
head(messy_adult[, .(date1, date2, date3, date4)])

 date1               date2      date3      date4
1: 2017-07-10                <NA> 2017-01-19 2017-01-21
2: 2017-12-31 2017-12-17 00:00:00 2017-06-06 2017-06-08
3: 2017-10-12 2017-11-22 00:00:00 2017-07-03 2017-07-05
4: 2017-09-06 2017-01-23 00:00:00 2017-07-19 2017-07-21
5: 2017-03-02 2017-06-25 01:00:00 2017-05-16 2017-05-18
6: 2017-10-04 2017-08-20 01:00:00 2017-04-02 2017-04-04
```

Hope it helps

Disclamer: I'm the author of this package.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the solution I was looking for. On a side note, how does one find search hidden gems from the sea list of packages in CRAN. Any search tips?

Comment: Sadly no :/ Ask and talk to as much people as possible ;)

Comment: A small blip I noticed while installing dataPreparation package. This package has been updated to 0.2 version but while installing using R Studio using install packages option it looks for 0.1 version and hence always gives an error. Where should one report such discrepancies

Comment: Can you please report error on https://github.com/ELToulemonde/dataPreparation/issues ?

Comment: Thanks will do, I did realize you being the author, there are couple other errors/clarifications which I will report in above link some time soon

Comment: Submitted few comments.